# What does { .. } mean in a pattern?

Tags: syntax, rust, pattern-matching

I found the following piece of code in the [doc](https://actix.rs/docs/errors/#recommended-practices-in-error-handling) about [actix](https://actix.rs/):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate failure;
use actix_web::{error, http, HttpResponse};

#[derive(Fail, Debug)]
enum UserError {
    #[fail(display = "Validation error on field: {}", field)]
    ValidationError { field: String },
}

impl error::ResponseError for UserError {
    fn error_response(&self) -> HttpResponse {
        match *self {
            UserError::ValidationError { .. } =>
                HttpResponse::new(http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST),
        }
    }
}
```

What does `{ .. }` mean here?

Comment: [Appendix B: Operators and Symbols](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) — *`..` - `variant(x, ..)`, `struct_type { x, .. }` - “And the rest” pattern binding*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [pattern-matching destructuring wildcard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#destructuring) that allows one to not need to specify all the members of an object. In this case:

```
UserError::ValidationError { .. }
```

It is enough for that `match` branch that the enum variant is `ValidationError`, regardless of its contents (in this case `field`):

```
enum UserError {
    #[fail(display = "Validation error on field: {}", field)]
    ValidationError { field: String },
}
```

It is also useful when one is concerned only with some members of an object; consider a `Foo` struct containing `baz` and `bar` fields:

```
struct Foo {
    bar: usize,
    baz: usize,
}
```

If you were only interested in `baz`, you could write:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Foo { bar: 0, baz: 1 };

    match x {
        Foo { baz, .. } => println!("{}", baz), // prints 1
        _ => (),
    }
}
```